# Call Image to Load Using Galleria Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a jQuery gallery script called [Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/), in conjunction with a [wordpress theme I'm working on.](http://photography.bramblingdesign.com/) The problem (as you can see) is that no image loads right off the bat, as it should. Is there any sort of workaround you can think of, to force the image to be loaded into that ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could trigger a "click" event on one of the thumbnail images that the plugin wraps itself around.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to work. I wen't with just displaying the first image always that gets overlapped by the others when you click on them.

Answer (score 0):

In the unordered list of  the images you want to show, add the following to the opening  li-tag of the image you want to load by default:

**class="active"**

Now that image will load off the bat.

Grtz,
Denios